# How do I Bind my Ajax Call Parameter to My Controllers Model Parameter

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, data-binding

I can't figure out what I am missing here.  I am trying to populate a Jquery Object and send that object to a Controller that has a Model as a parameter and have it bind correctly.

I know the Ajax Call works because i hit my breakpoint in the Controller.

Here is my Jquery to create the object that i will send via ajax

```
    var testObj = {};
    testObj.empNum = '1234';
```

Here is my Ajax Call:

```
var url = BASE_URL + "Assessment/testing";
$.post({
    url: url,
    data: {
          test: testObj
          },
    success: function (data) {
               console.log(data)
           },
    dataType: 'JSON'
});
```

Here is my Model:

```
public class test
{
    public string empNum { get; set; }
}
```

And My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult testing(test t)
{
    return Json(t, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am expecting the t in my controller to contain the test model with the empNum = 1234 but it keeps coming back as null.

Comment: Have you checked your browser to see what it's sending to the controller?

Comment: Yes, it sends the object just as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to waste everyone's time but here was the issue:

This line in the controller has a parameter of t:

```
public JsonResult testing(test t)
```

In my Ajax Call, the parameter name must match the parameter name on the controller.  So in this case; test should be changed to t to match the controller

```
       data: {
          test: testObj
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to convert js object to the c# model

```
$.post({
url: url,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: JSON.stringify(testObj),
```

or for multiple parameters:

```
$.post({
url: url,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: JSON.stringify( {test: testObj} ),
```

Comment: This did not work.  It appears in the console that it converts the object to a string, hence the name but does not Bind it to the model.  Thanks